# Can the sequence of complete graphs coarsely embed into Hilbert space?

Tags: graph-theory, metric-embeddings, coarse-geometry

Basically the title. If I have the metric space which is the disjoint union of the sequence of complete graphs, and the usual graph metric, has it been shown that the metric space can be coarsely embedded into a Hilbert space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis then the vectors $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_n$ all have unit distance from each other, so you can embed countably many cliques, each isometrically. I'm not sure whether this is a coarse embedding because you haven't told us what the distance is between disjoint cliques.